# Recyclerview not scrolling to the correct position with snaphelper

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a problem with my recyclerview, i want to make it automatically scroll to a position and even when it scrolls, it doesn't place to the correct position. The example in the following gif.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAUSP.gif)

here is part of my code:

```
final RecyclerView anioList = root.findViewById(R.id.dia_picker);
    final RecyclerView monthList = root.findViewById(R.id.mes_picker);

final ArrayList<DateBean> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
final ArrayList<DateBean> arrayList2 = new ArrayList<>();

final PickerAdapter adapter = new PickerAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
final PickerAdapter adapter2 = new PickerAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList2);

 final LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(
                getActivity(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                false);

        final LinearLayoutManager manager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(
                getActivity(),
                LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
                false);

final LinearSnapHelper snapHelper = new LinearSnapHelper();

final LinearSnapHelper snapHelper2 = new LinearSnapHelper();

snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(anioList);
snapHelper2.attachToRecyclerView(monthList);

anioList.setLayoutManager(manager);
monthList.setLayoutManager(manager2);


anioList.setOnFlingListener(snapHelper);
monthList.setOnFlingListener(snapHelper2);

anioList.setAdapter(adapter);
monthList.setAdapter(adapter2);


monthList.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
                    if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        centerView = snapHelper2.findSnapView(manager2);
                        // Getting position of the center/snapped item.
                        int pos = manager2.getPosition(centerView);
                        adapter2.changeSize(pos);
                        mes = arrayList2.get(pos).getDate();
                        if (pos==2)
                            diaList.scrollToPosition((arrayList3.size()) - 3);

                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: What is the correct position? What do you expect to happen? It is not clear from your description and video. Something to do with leap year? You don't need the two calls to `setOnFlingListener()` although that is probably not the issue.

Comment: diaList.scrollToPosition((arrayList3.size()) - 3);